# .show() doesn't show!

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready({
$('#sh').click(function(){
$('#container').show();

});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#container {
width:350px;
height:350px;
border:1px solid #000000;
display:none;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<p>paragraph 1</p>
</div>

<div>
<a href="#" id="sh">show</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

clicking on link doesn't trigger .show() at all!
What am i doing wrong??
Update: i tried $(document).ready({...  it doesn't help!

Comment: Look at Jonathan Sampson's suggested answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155533/show-doesnt-show/5155604#5155604 ) .

Comment: You forgot about the `function` in `$(document).ready(function() {` ;) check Jonathan Sampson's and mine solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to keep in mind, load the scripts only after the document has finished loading:

```
$(function(){
  /* Scripts here will run only
     after the document has loaded */
});
```

Also, be sure to [prevent the default behavior](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) of links when using them to trigger actions:

```
$(function(){
  $("#sh").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#container").show();
  });
});
```

With these changes, the code works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/apsje/

Comment: Good call with adding the prevent default. Also, kudos for a JSFiddle.

Comment: My pleasure, @DrStrangeLove. We've all made this mistake from time to time :)

Answer (score 1):

add your jquery code between this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

...

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

Because if you call your script before the real HTML, the elements you're referring to doesn't exist yet.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#sh').click(function(){
    $('#container').show();
})
```

By using the ready event on $(document), you make sure the DOM is completely loaded and ready to be interacted with.

Answer (score 1):

The browser has not yet rendered **#sh** when you are binding the click.

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sh').click(function(){
    $('#container').show();

  });
});
```

It binds the click after the document has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running before the elements are present in the DOM. Your script block should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( function()
  {
    $( '#sh' ).click( function()
    {
      $( '#container' ).show();
    } );
  } );
</script>
```

Comment: Ouch, there were no answers when I started posting, then--blammo--there were like 5. I got beat out bad!

Answer (score 0):

Or place the script before `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sh').click(function(){
        $('#container').show();

    });
});
```